# extracting png file from app

Tags: android

I have extracted some png files from one app. I cannot open them using android gallery neither on windows.

Can you help understanding what is really this file and what should be changed in order to view it?

here are the first few lines of the HEX code of the png.

67 3e 65 09 38 a1 25 50 42 d3 14 be c8 23 b1 3d
06 e2 4e 38 f7 c0 36 58 7d 06 2b 1c af 10 6b 4c
bd 1f dd ae 7a 9d 68 8c 89 26 22 7a ea ca 66 b8
99 80 9e a4 48 1b 1b a3 22 96 b6 08 2f 93 c3 c1
57 12 d1 8f 31 22 02 7c ac 29 32 5a d3 cb 48 67
c5 d1 09 9d 82 2a 58 d6 3d 41 47 7a fa de c7 88

Edit:The file is named with png extension. I extracted them from data/data folder. Tried to open it on windows. The above code is when opening it with HEX editot

Comment: It doesn't have PNG header so how do you know it's png file?

Comment: You need to reverse the .apk in order to decrypt the file

Comment: How did you extract this?

Comment: A file with a png file extension does not necessary contain a png file. Alternatively the file can be encrypted. Decompile the APK file e.g. using Jadx to understand how the file is loaded. Of course this requires Java development skills.